# Cloud Talent Solution API v3 - Project 292824132082 is temporarily blacklisted

Tags: google-api-explorer

I am getting the below error when i tried to execute Google Talent API in API Explorer using Default Credentials.

403

- Show headers -

{
 "error": {
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Project 292824132082 is temporarily blacklisted.. Request ID for tracking: 91ab3b1c-bda7-4578-96c8-a11dd9a65e6d:APAb7IR5Od8zMXJ58Ey037jd+dTgOcPfSg==",
  "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
 }
}

Could you pleaes help with why I am not able to execute the API in API Explorer?

Comment: I just had an error pop up with that same project number listed. I assume that project is somehow a default project for something, and you need to set credentials explicitly somewhere.